# Whats does -- do exactly

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I was doing a simple if(left(cells IN NUMBER FORMAT);things;otherthings) formula and it was not working. I evaluated it and it turns out the left was returning "7" instead of 7. It bugs me.

I have double checked and even converted the range to number multiple times. Still return the number as string.

I don't understand why I need the --left() which from my understanding was turning the value of a string into number if possible otherwise return error.

There has to be something I'm missing.

```
SWITCH(--left(cell IN NUMBER FORMAT);6;things;7;otherthings;otherotherthings)
```

Without -- It will always take the otherotherthings route. With it works fine.

Can share the WB if required.

I'm contesting the duplicate. I'm not converting a bool to a number, and if I am i'd like to know exactly why my function is working and how LEFT(cell) can return a boolean.

Comment: `--` is double unary (two single outputs); with that, we can force the boolean output into a numeric property

Comment: You do not need -- to turn bool to number in excel wsf as far as I know.
    =True*10 will return 10.

Second left does not return a bolean, I feel this is not the same -- we are talking about. Or maybe I'm not understanding what i'm doing

Comment: `--` is like `=TRUE*-1*-1` so it is the same.  If you do any math with TRUE/FALSE it will turn it to the 1/0 respectively: `=TRUE+0`, `=TRUE*1`,...  It is just easier to use `--`.

Comment: I still don't understand how I can convert a value returned by left to a boolean value. 
And why would anyone ever need to convert true/false to number ? 
Sum(true;true;true) will return 3 you do not need sum(--true;--true;--true);  TRUE*10 will return 10. Isn't it automatic in excel?

Comment: Left does not return a boolean, but Any non 0 number used in an IF will return the TRUE value: `IF(54,"True","FALSE")` while 0 will return False `IF(0,"True","False")`

Comment: The actual formula is =SWITCH(--LEFT(CELL IN NUMBERFORMAT);6;something;7;somethingelse;othersomethingelse)

I still don't understand how converting a boolean apply to my situation. without the -- it always return the othersomethingelse result.

Comment: And try `=ISNUMBER(TRUE)` it returns FALSE, But `ISNUMBER(--TRUE)` returns TRUE.  There are formulas that will do the conversion but not all.  SUMPRODUCT will also not do it naturally, Nor will SWITCH or CHOOSE.  LEFT returns a string not a number and those need a number.

Comment: Ok interesting  ISNUMBER(TRUE) returning false & ISNUMBER(--TRUE) returning TRUE, 100% agree there you clearly see that -- convert bool to value but *1 would have done it too right ?
But My left returns "6" then it checks if 6 is equal to 6 and apply results if yes.
I'm never doing any test on the value of boolean ? much less using the value of the boolean in the test.I use -- before LEFT not before something that will return a boolean. I only care for true or false in my situation. I feel there is something I don't understand well there.

Comment: When I want to make sure left() returns a number, this works "=LEFT(A1,6)*1" the "*1" is sufficient as far as I have found.

Comment: Try this: `ISNUMBER(LEFT(617))` it returns FALSE.  Now try: `ISNUMBER(--LEFT(617))` which returns TRUE.  SWITCH requires that the types be consistent.  `=SWITCH(LEFT(617),"6","Test","NOT")` will return `Test` as a string equals a string but `=SWITCH(LEFT(D16),6,"Test","NOT")` does not match types.

Comment: Great I feel like I'm kind of understanding. I have tested and Indeed *1 makes left return a number too. There must be something in excel automaticly converting the value of LEFT to number if you try a mathematical operation with the result, Otherwise the result will be a string with composed of what LEFT returned.
I can be only that. Now why, any VB super expert aviable to explain us this behavior ? 

@Scott Ok for the comment on switch but when you don't specify a result in switch it mean this will be the else route. I'm not doing the mistake of testing a type vs another one.